# PostMessage results in "...a call to pinvoke function has unbalanced the stack c#..."

Tags: c#, postmessage

In a 32bit managed app I use Proecess.Start to load a 64bit .Net app.
Following that I PostMessage() from the 32bit app to the 64bit app using the MainWindowHandle.
The problem is that when the PostMessage() is called I get the error "A call to PInvoke function 'xxxx::PostMessage' has unbalanced the stack..."
After pressing continue everything works fine.
I am using VS 2017.
If I convert the 32bit app to 64bit no problem.
Also I don't get the problem when run the 32bit app outside the VS.
Both apps are in C#.
Can I just uncheck the PInvokeStackImbalance in MDA or is it something that I should "worry" about?

Thank you

Following is the code in a form to start a client app, dock its main form and set the handle of the current form to the client app.

```
    private const int SEND_HANDLE = WM_USER + 101;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, long wParam, long lParam);
    private void DoDock()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("test.exe");
        psi.Arguments = "";
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        pDocked = Process.Start(psi);

        while (hWndDocked == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            pDocked.WaitForInputIdle(1000);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            pDocked.Refresh();
            if (pDocked.HasExited)                
                return;
            hWndDocked = pDocked.MainWindowHandle;  //cache the window handle
        }

        PostMessage(hWndDocked, SEND_HANDLE, this.Handle.ToInt32(), 0);
    }
```

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: It signals you have memory corruption in your pinvoke code, so yeah this is something you should worry about. Post your PostMessage declaration.

Comment: You probably wrote wrong `PostMessage` declaration. Use [this](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/postmessage.html) one (the first one)

Comment: Following is the code in a form to start a client app, dock its main form and set the handle of the current form to the client app.

Comment: Not memory corruption, that exception quite reliably tells you that your [DllImport] declaration is wrong. It is, the last two arguments are IntPtr, not long.  Keels over when your program runs in 32-bit mode.   Do beware of VB6 declarations, widely present on the interwebs, they often use `Long` but that is a 32-bit integral type.  And are not fit to use a 64-bit program.  The pinvoke.net website is the better source of correct declarations.

Answer (score 1):

This normally means that your pinvoke declaration is wrong. [This website](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/postmessage.html) lists the correct declaration as:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool PostMessage(HandleRef hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```